# Android WebView Configuration Change Keyboard Glitch

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, android-orientation

I have a `textbox` at the bottom of my HTML file loaded in `WebView`.

In Portrait mode when keyboard is up and I change screen orientation, I can't see my `textbox` but when I start typing then it gets scrolled and `textbox` gets shown.

And in Landscape mode when keyboard is up and I change screen orientation i get a black space between `textbox` and keyboard, and even when I'm typing it still stays there.
How to avoid this problem?

Screen-shots are as follow:

**Initial Stage:**

[image]

**Changing Orientation from Portrait to Landscape:**

[image]
[image]

**Changing Orientation from Landscape to Portrait:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should provide your layout code.

Comment: It isn't an android layout. Its a webview that I'm using fullscreen. Anyways the problem has been resolved. It was just some javascript code that I executed to refresh the webview's content whenever orientation changes.